# Create Custom calendar in PHP

Tags: php, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I  need to create custom calendar with PHP. I know how to create a Gregorian Calendar but this one is bit tricky.

```
2090 = {30,31,32,32,32,29,30,31,31,30,29,30}
```

^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^

Year     No of Days in the months

Is it possible to create one such calendar ?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: _"Year No of Days in the months"_ I'm sorry what? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Calendar-in-PHP

Comment: @Epodax This is actually a Nepali Calendar which doesn't follow the normal Gregorian calendar format. That's why I gave the custom year and the number of days in the 12 months.

I did like this in PHP to create array to get month name as well.
$year = array('Baisakh'=>30,'Jestha'=>29,'Ashar'=>32.....);

Now I need to start the starting day from anyday mentioned. Hope this elaborates more.

Answer (score 0):

Create a json file with all your custom year and days of months
Like this

```
[
  {
    "year":1930,
    "months": 
    [
     30,
     30,
     30,
     30,
     30,
     30,
     30,
     30,
     30,
     30,
     30
    ]
  },
   {
    "year":1920,
    "months": 
    [
     30,
     30,
     30,
     30,
     30,
     30,
     30,
     30,
     30,
     30,
     30
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since each year has the same months/days except for leap years, you have only to check if your year is leap by using `date('L')` which returns `1` when is leap.

```
$year = 2020; // is leap
$output = array(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);
$output[1] = date('L', strtotime($year.'-01-01')) == 1 ? 29 : 28;
```

Comment: This is Nepali Calendar, thus no leap year in here.